# Phonegap (android) not working on specific phones

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, genymotion

I developed an app for android using phonegap on Eclipse.

The app works fine in all the phones I've tested. It even works on all the virtual devices I've used on Genymotion.

BUT, on one phone (Android 2.3.6) it gets stuck when the plugins are called and I get the errors below. The strange thing is that it works perfectly on another phone using Android 2.3.6. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Errors:

```
09-01 08:07:50.671: E/ActivityThread(13600): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
09-01 08:07:51.156: E/ActivityThread(13600): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600): Uncaught exception from plugin
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.requestAllPaths(FileUtils.java:866)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.execute(FileUtils.java:348)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:227)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:580)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-01 08:07:55.500: E/PluginManager(13600):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 08:08:26.796: E/ActivityThread(13600): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
```

Answer (score 0):

I fiexed it after rebuilding the entire project from scratch.

I do not know why it was not working on some specific phones but I probably messed something up along the way.

Thanks

Jennie